# How to connect to nested paths in React-admin? (e.g. http://my.api.to/users/active)

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have API paths like http://my.api.to/user/active where /user is a working api call as well as /user/active.

How should I add them to < Resource name="" >, so my dataProvider accepts it?

I use the default ra-data-json-server's dataprovider with minor changes.

my GET_LIST looks like this:

```
        case GET_LIST: {
            const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
            const { field, order } = params.sort;
            const query = {
                ...fetchUtils.flattenObject(params.filter),
                //filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
                sort: field,
                order: order,
                start: (page - 1) * perPage,
                end: page * perPage,
            };
                url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
            }
            break;
        }
```

I also tried to tweak the url based on the resource name without any luck:

```
        case GET_LIST: {
            const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
            const { field, order } = params.sort;
            const query = {
                ...fetchUtils.flattenObject(params.filter),
                //filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
                sort: field,
                order: order,
                start: (page - 1) * perPage,
                end: page * perPage,
            };
            if (resource === 'clicks/monthly'){
                url = `${apiUrl}/clicks/monthly?year=2019&${stringify(query)}`;
            } else {
                url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
            }
            break;
        }
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Can you clarify your use case? What are you trying to achieve? Not technically, explain the feature you are implementing

Comment: I have an api call that goes to http://my.api.to/user - which is working fine, i can get that data from it without any problem... but i have another api call, which the api provides under http://my.api.to/user/active - now this one does not work, even if i set in the resource name that `name="user/active"`

sample code that does not work:

`<Resource name="clicks/monthly" options={{ label: 'Havi összesítés' }} list={ClickMonthly} />`

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try naming your resource without a slash, for example `users-active`

```
  <Admin
        dataProvider={jsonServerProvider('http://my.api.to')}
        dashboard={Dashboard}
    >
         <Resource name="users" icon={UserIcon} list={UserList}  options={{ label: 'All users' }}/>
         <Resource name="users-active" icon={UserIcon} list={UserList} options={{ label: 'Active users' }}/>
    </Admin>
```

In your dataprovider, you'll then be able to route the call as you want:

```
     case GET_LIST: {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        const query = {
            ...fetchUtils.flattenObject(params.filter),
            //filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
            sort: field,
            order: order,
            start: (page - 1) * perPage,
            end: page * perPage,
        };
        if (resource === 'users-active'){
                url = `${apiUrl}/users/active?${stringify(query)}`;
            } else {
                url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
        }
        break;
    }
```